# Javascript function return un-defined

Tags: javascript

Why would one case return an object (func1) but the other return undefined (func2)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGsZ1.png)

```
function func1(){
     return {
     bar: "hello"
    };
 }
 function func2(){
     return
    {
     bar: "hello"
    };
 }
```

Comment: Why did you edit your post to remove the posted code? Post your code, not a link to an image of your code.

Comment: Func 2 line 2 execution ends because of ASI.